# How to provide absolute filepaths in HTML

Tags: html

I am attempting to load an image, located at

```
/tmp/sample.png
```

The image is there, and I can cd into the folder and see it. However when I type

```
<img src="/tmp/sample.png" alt="Sample Image">
```

The alternate text is displayed instead of the image. However, if I move the image to my current directory and use

```
<img src="./sample.png" alt="Working image">
```

This works perfectly.

**What am I missing in the absolute filepath?**

Note: I have tried

```
<img src "http://localhost/tmp/sample.png">
<img src "tmp/sample.png">
<img src "../../../../../tmp/sample.png>
```

with no luck. I have also attempted the strategies listed in the duplicate post, those do not work for me either.

**Edit:**

**/**

**home**

--> user

------>PycharmProjects

---------->webapp

-------------->dashboard

------------------>hud.html

**tmp**

--> sample.png

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is the `tmp` folder web accessible?

Comment: @j08691 what do you mean? It's a folder on my computer

Comment: What's the path to your web root? Is `tmp` under it?

Comment: What do you mean by web root? tmp is under my root directory on my computer. If I use the command line and do cd /tmp and then ls.. sample.png appears

Comment: Are you working in a framework environment or just plain html

Comment: This just means the tmp is not under your webroot, @j08691 is on the right track

Comment: upload  u r file structure screenshot ..

Comment: @laddie_03 The directory that index.html (or whatever you have called it) lives in.

Comment: Are you running an actual web server, or just opening a file locally on your computer?

Comment: @SteveK plain html

Comment: @HunterMcMillen do I have to create that?

Comment: @j08691 locally

Comment: @laddie_03 you have a file with some html in it that you are loading in your web browser locally. What folder is the html file in? and how does it relate to `/tmp/`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, that folder is located further down the file tree. It's 3 or 4 levels below the root. Whereas tmp is at the root

Comment: @StardustGogeta, no luck. Doesn't that imply that the tmp folder is in my current directory?

Comment: @laddie_03 Yes, I'm sorry, I misread the question initially. Is it possible to use `src="../../../sample.png"` or something like that in this instance?

Comment: @StardustGogeta no luck there either. I am able to cd to the desired location using that but the image still isn't appearing

Comment: @laddie_03 Are you able to take a screenshot of the directory/file structure so that we can get a better idea of what is going on?

Comment: can you open the src path in the browser? does it display the image?

Comment: @TheRuler I'm using a container so I don't know if that will work. But I tried it and no luck

Comment: @StardustGogeta I cannot upload a screenshot of my file structure as I have changed the names of some of the folders and files for security purposes

Comment: @laddie_03 Perhaps you inadvertently changed something between your version and the version you posted on StackOverflow, since otherwise I do not know what could be causing this.

Comment: @laddie_03 if the image located at `/tmp` is related to your web app 3 or 4 levels down it _should_ be in that directory alongside the HTML. Many people create a folder called *images* for just this purpose. You would then reference those images with `...src="/images/<image-name>.<image-extension>"...`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, the location of those images is predetermined and this HTML code cannot be moved to that location, it has a predetermined location as well unfortunately. So am I correct in thinking that html cannot access files above the working directory of the html file attempting to access?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen, I know that it can work when it is in the same directory, I tried that earlier and mentioned it in my post.

Comment: @laddie_03 No, that is not correct that HTML cannot reference files above the working directory. The `src="../../image.jpg"` style path should (and does) work if you have the right path written out.

Comment: @StardustGogeta I see, I am just as confused as you then. Because if I go to the command line from the directory where my html code is and type "cd ../../../../../tmp" then type "ls" the sample.png appears. But when I include that exact same filepath in the HTML script nothing happens

Comment: @laddie_03 That is quite odd. Unfortunately, without more information, I don't think I'll be able to help figure out what is happening here. (In regards to your edit, I am not the one who downvoted the question, but if I had to guess, I would predict it is because there is not enough info to be able to replicate the issue on our end.)

Comment: You need to show an image or diagram of how the tmp folder is located in relation to your html file you are loading in your browser.  Here is a sample one I found on the internets: http://www.javawebtutor.com/images/servlets/web_application.gif

Comment: if you can't open the src, neither can the img tag. what kind of web server are you running? what happens if you try to open the Src without the filename?

Comment: @TheRuler, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. I can load images if they are in the current working directory or below the working directory in the file tree.

Comment: @laddie_03 I think the issue is with the web server. how did you set up the project?

Comment: Simply put, when you set up a web address for a host/domain, you tell the web server at which path the root is. If yours is "webapp" (normally where you have the "index.html" located), then the "tmp" will not be accessible for web requests. If you create a folder under "webapp" (if that is the one) named "tmp" and place the image there, it will work with "/tmp/sample.png"

Comment: @TheRuler, I am running this locally. I simply made an HTML file and launched the HTML file on my browser.

Comment: @LGSon so absolute filepaths only work from the index.html file level and below?

Comment: By default, yes, that is correct. If you want to store e.g. images elsewhere, you need read/stream them using server side tech, or setup an alias for such path.

Comment: Based on your comment, running it using a local html file, you need to do something like `../../../../tmp/sample.png`

Comment: @j08691 -- OP appears to run it locally...and not saying until now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314121/how-to-provide-absolute-filepaths-in-html?noredirect=1#comment101121885_57314121 ... so closed it + downvote from me

Comment: @LGSon, I've already tried that. Earlier in the comments. Also, in my post I have localhost mentioned. I don't quite understand the downvote?

Comment: Launching a html file in the browser, locally, is not the same as `localhost`. `localhost` on a Windows PC is running as a web server (IIS), and with that my comment (and dupe link) explains it. The downvote is because you provide different info to use when we ask, and haven't properly explained how the html file is served.

Comment: @LGSon I have answered the questions to the best of my ability. If I had a deeper understanding then I wouldn't be asking for help. I am a beginner to HTML development.

Comment: @LGSon, I had previously looked at other posts on StackOverflow with no success, hence this post. My apologies for not making that clear.

Comment: I understand that, still, to make use of the answers you get here, one need some basic understanding, if one doesn't have that, one need to start with it. SO is not a tutorial site in that way. In this comment of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57314121/how-to-provide-absolute-filepaths-in-html#comment101121746_57314121 I explained how-to, if using a web server (which `localhost` indicates you use). The dupe link go somewhat deeper with how to write a path. With basic knowledge you will make something out of those.

Comment: If you on the other hand simply double click on a html file, it will open as a local file (the address in the browser will look like `file:///C:/path/index.html`), and that is not the same as `localhost`, which looks like `http://localhost/index.html`. If that is the case, the `/../../../tmp/sample.png` should work, though you need to make sure you have the correct amount of parent directory set `../`

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
<img src="tmp/sample.png" alt="Sample Image" />
```

Skip the "/" at the start, since you have no web server and a root directory.

Comment: No luck, I've tried that